# Python: "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'weekofyear' ", why do I get this only in comprehension lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select all records with the same week of the year of the missing records in a pandas DataFrame:

I can find the week of  the year for the missing data without problems:

```
df_copy[df_copy['reference'].isna()].index.weekofyear
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 18, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
            23, 28, 28, 30, 33, 39, 39, 39, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43,
            43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48,
            49, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50],
           dtype='int64', name='Timestamp')
```

When I put the same expression in a comprehension list so I can try to find all the records in the Data Frame with the same week of years of the missing data it gives me this error:

```
[x for x in df_copy if x.index.weekofyear in df_copy[df_copy['reference'].isna()].index.weekofyear]
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-450-2d12edd41791> in <module>
----> 1 [x for x in df_copy if x.index.weekofyear in df_copy[df_copy['reference'].isna()].index.weekofyear]

<ipython-input-450-2d12edd41791> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [x for x in df_copy if x.index.weekofyear in df_copy[df_copy['reference'].isna()].index.weekofyear]

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'weekofyear'
```

EDIT-----------------------------
I see now that the problem is not the expression but with the x in the comprehension.

```
[x for x in df_copy]
```

gives me:

```
['reference', 'next_value']
```

Only the strings of the column names.

Answer (score 1):

`[x for x in df_copy]` will only give you the column names. I guess you want to loop through the rows - use `[x for x in df_copy.iterrows()]`

Try this:

```
print([x.weekofyear for x, row in df_copy[df_copy['reference'].isna()].iterrows()])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew the iterrows() function, but I iterated over only the values so I couldn't get the index, I didn't know it returned couples (index,values) that solves a lot of mysteries.

Comment: @9879ypxkj Glad that I was able to help! Cheers :)